# Can I use RBF neural network to forecast time series in R language?

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series, forecasting

There is a time series of the number of jobs in manufacture between 1978 to 2017. I want to use Radial Basis Neural Network to forecast the number of jobs in two years. Is it possible? If it is, could you please write the code in R language? Many thanks! I wrote some codes here :

```
install.packages("RSNNS")

library(RSNNS)

data <- read.csv("jobs.csv",header = TRUE)

tsA01 <- ts(data$`A-01`,start = c(1978,2),end = c(2017,1),frequency = 4)
```

part of data as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: You'll get more responses if you include a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example of the data, you have a very simple dataset: a response variable (number of jobs), and a single covariate (date). If that is truly the limit of your data, there is no need for a Neural Network approach. Neural Networks and other Supervised Machine Learning approaches are really only necessary when you have tons of features (i.e., covariates, also called "p"), typically such that p >> n (number of observations). In this specific case, I would start with a simple linear regression that perhaps takes things like month or season into account as covariates. If the regression looks good, you can then make predictions about future time points.

If you do have more complex data than you eluded to in your question, there is a great textbook for machine learning that is available online for free. It includes a number of laboratory chapters written in R to help guide you through various analyses, but I would invest the time in reading about the pros and cons of the various approaches before you decide to use Neural Networks specifically. You can find the textbook here: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ (and just click "Download the book PDF".